# Maven doesn't look in the local repository

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I'm trying to manage several projects with Maven, which have a number of interdependencies. This is what I did:

- I built one project with `mvn package`.
- I tried to build another project that depends on the other with `mvn package`.

That produces this output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building classj 0.5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/tbodt/jrestack/1.0/jrestack-1.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.tbodt:jrestack:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/tbodt/jrestack/1.0/jrestack-1.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.332 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-04-09T17:45:17-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/58M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project classj: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.tbodt:classj:jar:0.5-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.tbodt:jrestack:jar:1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

As you can see, Maven tried and failed to download my project from the central repository. It is in the local repository, however. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

To install your first project in a local repository, run this:

```
mvn install
```